# Why does basic_string::assign not have a r-value overload?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdstring, rvalue

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/assign) assign doesn't have a r-value overload. The kind of function signature I was expecting is:

```
basic_string::assign(basic_string::basic_string &&param);
```

I checked the implementation for MSVC-2014 and CGI's implementation which do not provide this overload. The obvious advantage of this would be in cases like

```
string final; 
while(true){
    string tmp;
    // do some operation on tmp
    if (ConditionSatisfied){
       final.assign(move(tmp));
       break;
    } 
}    
// do further operations on final
```

Is it because the use cases of this would be rare? Or is there is any design flaw to include the overload.

Comment: You could simply `final = std::move(temp);`.

Comment: As Cubbi said on cppreference: There is `basic_string& assign( basic_string&& str );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same very page you linked does show the overload you're looking for:

```
basic_string& assign( basic_string&& str );
```

> 4) Replaces the contents with those of str using move semantics. str
>   is in undefined state after the operation.

Second, your claim that it's not implemented in MSVC (as of 2013) is dubious, considering that it's documented on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y22b7w38.aspx).

```
basic_string(
    basic_string&& _Right
);
```

<sup>There is no Visual Studio 2014, there is however "14" CTP, which isn't meant for production environments. Visual Studio 2015 is version 14.0. The actual compiler number is 19.00.</sup>